# Android RecyclerView with progress indicator and animation

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, android-recyclerview

At Material Design guides there is a pattern for loading and displaying all content at once.

[Link](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsQkFTSm13bUFLX00/components-progressactivity-behavior-Loading_Files_Circular_xhdpi_003.webm)

how to implement it using RecyclerView?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply do it by toggling visibility of progressbar and recyclerview.

In your layout,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

According to above layout, before your data is ready, progressbar is showing on screen. After your data is ready, you can switch visibility like that.

```
mRecyclerAdapter.setData(mData); // need to implement setter method for data in adapter
mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: How is it possible to do the same animations for the recyclerview items?

Comment: Hi, @MotassemJalal , you just need to do the same thing, but now with Adapter rows.